# Abbreviate a numeric vector when displaying it in the console

Tags: r

I'd like to abbreviate a numeric vector when displaying it through the R console. I tried already the function `?abbreviate`, but it does not the thing I want. In fact I want the whole vector to be abbreviated, not each element of the vector. In addition, I want to pass `...` at the breaking position so to indicate it goes on. How can I make this?

```
x = 1:100
x 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `str()`.

```
x <- 1:100
str(x, vec.len = 2.5, give.head = FALSE)
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
```

But David Arenburg makes a good suggestion with `cat()`.  Here's a function which allows you to adjust the length more precisely.

```
f <- function(x, n) cat(x[1:n], "...")
f(x, 5)
# 1 2 3 4 5 ...
f(x, 9)
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
```

**Update:**  In response to your comment about putting the text name of the input before the values, you can adjust the function as follows.

```
f <- function(x, n) {
    cat(substitute(x), head(x, n), if(n < length(x)) "...")
}

stuff <- 1:100
f(stuff, 6)
# stuff 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
f(stuff, 12)
# stuff 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...
```

Comment: That a nice one, but I wonder if just `cat(x[1:6], "...")` should be enough

Comment: Yeah, that's a better one

Comment: I've never seen use for `give.head` before

Comment: The only problem with this is that it paste the text after the vector, see:         `> x <- 1:100`
`> cat("text", str(x, vec.len = 2.5, give.head = FALSE))`
`1 2 3 4 5 6 ...`
`text`

Comment: Then you should place you "text" inside the function as: 'f <- function(x,n) cat("text": x[1:n], "...")' that should do the trick; I didn't test though.

Comment: @daniel Indeed. Even better: `f <- function(x,n) cat("text": x[1:n], "...", "\n")` does the whole thing I was looking for at once. Thank you all for this.